# JQuery if certain textboxe's are empty, disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I've seen plenty examples of people disabling buttons if textboxes are empty but I haven't found any which will disable a button for only certain textboxes. I'm new to Jquery and I know it is pseudo coded but you can get the idea. Which Jquery function do I have to call so that it is constantly checking? And how can I use an or statement in the if clause to determine if any textbox field is empty?

```
if( $('#txtEvent').val.length === 0 || $("#txtID").val.length === 0)
 {
  $('#btnSave').attr("disabled", "disabled");
 }
else 
 {
  $('#btnSave').attr("enabled", "enabled");
 }
```

Form Controls

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEvent" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
< asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"" Text="Save and Next" />
```

Comment: `.val()` instead of `.val`

Comment: If you just have these two inputs in your page, you can use `$('input:text:empty').length > 0`

Comment: If there are more than two text boxes then you might want to add a class to all those textboxes and this class can be used as a JQUERY selector with @Aruns solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it two different ways:

```
if (!$("#txtEvent").val()) { //undefined will yield false
//call a method! .val() not .val
    $("#btnSave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
    $("#btnSave").attr("enabled", "enabled");
}
```

Or:

```
if ($("#txtEvent").length > 0) {
    $("#btnSave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
} else {
    $("#btnSave").attr("enabled", "enabled");
}
```

If you want these constantly running, wrap them in:

```
$("#txtEvent").on("change", function() { //code });
//using the onchange event will trigger the code whenever the txtbox changes.
//you can also use onblur if you want it to trigger AFTER the txtbox loses focus
```

Please note you'll have to convert these into proper asp code! This is simply a logistical answer.

Comment: ok great thanks for the input, how can I check if multiple textboxes are null and in return multiple on change functions

Comment: with jquery you can select multiple by adding a comma between ids or class selectors. Based on those conditions, disable whatever. It might be a lot of if statments if you're disabling different buttons each time, if not it can be done in 1 with multiple jquery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $empties = $('#txtEvent, #txtID').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
})

$('#btnSave').prop("disabled", $empties.length === 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is two years old question, I would like to show another way using `bind`. See the text `'keyup mouseup cut paste'`

This will also work if you ***cut*** or ***paste*** text as well as keyboard input. Also this will work if we click the little cross in the text box to clear the text( using `mouseup`).

[image]

OP stated that disable a button for "only certain textboxes".
Say we have following text boxes

```
<input type="text" name="tbox1" id="txtbox1" />
<input type="text" name="tbox2" id="txtbox2" />
<input type="text" name="tbox3" id="txtbox3" />
<input type="text" name="tbox4" id="txtbox4" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="button" value="Save and Next" disabled />
```

If we need to enable/disable the button based on values entered in to txtBox1 OR txtBox3 then we can use this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#txtbox1, #txtbox3").bind('keyup mouseup cut paste', function () {
          var txt = $(this);
          setTimeout(function () {
              $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', $(txt).val() == ''); 
           }, 100);
      });
  });
</script>
```

If we need to enable/disable the button only when both txtBox1 AND txtBox3 are not empty then we can use this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#txtbox1, #txtbox3").bind('keyup mouseup cut paste', function () {
         setTimeout(function () {
             ($('#txtbox1').val() && $('#txtbox3').val()) ? $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', false) : $('#btnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
         }, 100);
      });
  });
</script>
```