# How to dynamically enable/disable a button

Tags: javascript

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478336/jquery-if-certain-textboxes-are-empty-disable-button), I tried to create a similar validation function:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $("#my_name_id").on("change", function() {
                if (!$("#my_name_id").val()) {
                $("#button_id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else {
                $("#button_id").attr("enabled", "enabled");
            }
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="test_form" id="test_form_id" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="my_name" id="my_name_id" placeholder="Type your name"/>
            <button type="submit" id="button_id">My button</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, I would like to continually check to see if the input box contains any characters. If it does, then the button should be enabled (clickable). If the input box does not contain any text, then the button should be disabled.

However, in my case the button always remains enabled. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't you just do `<input name="my_name" required />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `prop`, not `attr`. After all your code will become simpler:

```
$("#my_name_id").on("change keyup", function() {
    $("#button_id").prop("disabled", !this.value);
})
.trigger('change');
```

Also note how you can use `trigger` in order to run initial check on page load automatically. I also included `keyup` event for this to work as you type.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7nywe/

Comment: Your example works if I type some text, then click outside the input box. However, I would like it so that as soon as you type something, the button becomes enabled (without having to click outside first).

Comment: Cool, that worked :) Could you please update your answer to include the `keyup`?

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided works, but when i create a .html file on my desktop and try it manually it doesn't work (the button remains enabled). Is there any additional code I need to include/enable?

Comment: Make sure you execute this code when DOM is loaded. Try to wrap it into document ready closure `$(function() { /* code goes here */ })`. Or move the code *after* the form tag.

Comment: When you say `DOM is loaded`, do you mean wrapping the entire solution in another `$(function() { $("#my_name_id").... })`? I did however place the `<script>...</script>` block after the `form` section, same results.

Comment: I found that if I use a plain .html file it doesn't work. However, I put the code inside an existing django template, and it worked. So maybe there is some additional stuff that needs to get installed/loaded. Anyway, I was eventually going to move it to a django template, so all is well :)

Comment: Glad to hear you found out a way around!

Answer (score 1):

No `enabled` attribute in HTML for , so manipulate the `disabled` attribute:

```
<script>
$("#my_name_id").on("change", function () {
    if (!$("#my_name_id").val()) {
        $("#button_id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#button_id").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}).trigger('change');;
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however the button is still clickable upon an initial loading of the html.

Comment: @DirtyPenguin Well, set it as `disabled` by default.

Comment: If I set it as `disabled` by default, when I start typing in text in the input box, the button is not `enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prop()`

```
$("#button_id").prop("disabled", true);  // disabled
$("#button_id").attr("disabled", false); // enabled
```

You should use `prop` when you are dealing with boolean types.